# Cube SSAS - Relative calendar

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx, dax, ssas-2012

I have a dimension DimDate (Year, month, days, quater) and in this dimension I would like to create a relative calendar corresponding to the relative year and relative month.
Eg in:
- Relative Year I would like to have a Member : current year, current year-1
- Relative Month i would like to have a member : Current month, current month -1, current month-2...

how to do it in SSAS?

Comment: which is it dax or mdx? that is very different if you actually want the code.  Create a Calculated Column (s) for each level of the hierarchy and then build the hierarchy itself

Comment: Yes - is it SSAS tabular or olap? Is it being built out of a star schema? If so, your first task is to add it to your date dimension table

Answer (score 0):

Use a "Relative period dimension"

The below SQL Scripts will create a relative period dimension table and view.

Add it to your DSV, 
create a dimension from it, 
set it to have "Current member" as the default,
set it to be non-aggregatable, 
add the cube script (provided in the cubeScript column in the table for convenience) into the calculations tab in your cube (you may need to change this to suit your dimension and hierarchy names)

The dimension should then be added to the cube, but NOT tied to any measure groups.  The wiring up is done with the cube script.

I've provided the default plus two examples of relative period calculations, but this can easily be extended as required. (eg. same period last year, prior full year, Thursday before last etc)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DimRelativePeriod](
[relativePeriodKey] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[relativePeriodCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
[relativePeriod] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[relativePeriodSortOrder] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_dimRelativePeriod_relativePeriodSortOrder]  DEFAULT ((1)),
[cubeScript] [varchar](max) NULL,
[sqlScript] [varchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dimRelativePeriod] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[relativePeriodKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE view [dbo].[vwDimRelativePeriod]
as
select 
relativePeriodKey, 
relativePeriodCode, 
relativePeriod, 
relativePeriodSortOrder
from 
[dbo].[DimRelativePeriod]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DimRelativePeriod] ON 

GO
INSERT [dbo].[DimRelativePeriod] ([relativePeriodKey], [relativePeriodCode], [relativePeriod], [relativePeriodSortOrder], [cubeScript], [sqlScript]) VALUES (1, N'CUR', N'Current Period', 1, NULL, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DimRelativePeriod] ([relativePeriodKey], [relativePeriodCode], [relativePeriod], [relativePeriodSortOrder], [cubeScript], [sqlScript]) VALUES (2, N'YTD', N'Year to Date', 2, N'SCOPE ([Relative Period].[Relative Period].&[YTD]);
THIS=  
iif([Date].[Calendar].currentmember.level.name = "Month",
aggregate(
[Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER.parent.parent.firstchild.firstchild:
[Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER*[Relative Period].[Relative Period].&[CUR]),''N/A'')
);
END SCOPE;', NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DimRelativePeriod] ([relativePeriodKey], [relativePeriodCode], [relativePeriod], [relativePeriodSortOrder], [cubeScript], [sqlScript]) VALUES (3, N'LTD', N'Life to Date', 3, N'SCOPE ([Relative Period].[Relative Period].&[LTD]);
THIS=  
aggregate(null:[Date].[Fiscal].CURRENTMEMBER*[Relative Period].[Relative Period].&[CUR]);
END SCOPE;', NULL)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[DimRelativePeriod] OFF 
GO
```